# How to return an object after looping through a list of them, without overloading the constructor without parameters?

Tags: c#

I've encountered this issue several times:

```
        internal Project GetProject(int projectId)
        {
            Project project = new Project; // *
            foreach (var p in this.projects)
            {
                if (p.projectId == projectId)
                {
                    return p;
                }
            }
            return project;
        }
```

*This does not work because the project class takes several parameters. It would be absurd though to come up with random parameters, just to live until the loop does its work.

Sometimes I find other ways around it, but generally I overload the constructor without parameters to solve it, which does not feel right though. Maybe there is a whole different way?

It is understandable that the method requires certainty that something is returned. I don't see either what to do if the right object is not found in the list, what to return in this case? An empty object not being the best thing? Apologies if this sounds like two questions, but I have an inkling the answer is one.

Comment: How about returning null? If you are using nullable reference types, you should change the return type to `Project?` as well.

Comment: Thanks loads, I have somehow been overseeing that option and was stuck building piles of stuff to get around it

Comment: @Sweeper Do you want to post it as an answer so I can select it? Maybe I should change the question title too then for more clarity

Comment: It depends on what you will do if the specific projectId is not found.

Comment: For now returning null suffices, the last comment solved this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the return type nullable, in this case:

```
internal Project? GetProject(int projectId)
        {
            foreach (var p in this.projects)
            {
                if (p.projectId == projectId)
                {
                    return p;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```